# Unfamiliar syntax - Query with Parameters in Braces at the beggining

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, syntax, parameter, sp-whoisactive

I have run [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) on one of our servers using the following syntax:

```
sp_whoisactive @get_plans = 1, @show_sleeping_spids = 0, @get_outer_command = 1, @get_locks = 1
```

and found a spid with the sql_command (the column shown when `@get_outer_command` is set to 1) as follows

```
(@p1 int,@p2 int)
Exec MyDatabase.MyProc @p1 @p2
```

When I try to run a query with this syntax on my test Adventureworks database:

```
(@be int)
SELECT  *
FROM    Person.Person
WHERE   BusinessEntityID = @be
```

I get the error

> Msg 1050, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   This syntax is only allowed for parameterized queries.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@FN".

so it seems to be something to do with parameterized queries. This makes sense as the variable @be is never set to a value

What is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, the (@be int) shown applies to parameterized queries. Applications often parameterize the queries using `sp_executesql`, and then sent them to the sql server.

The query will be cached as *(variables)QueryText*
. And ofcourse, the values won't be cached in the text, since the query is parameterized.

**Parameterized query example**

Test Data

```
CREATE SCHEMA PERSON;

CREATE TABLE Person.Person( BusinessEntityID int );

INSERT INTO Person.Person(BusinessEntityID)
VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

Query

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT  * FROM    Person.Person WHERE   BusinessEntityID = @be',N'@be int',@be=2
```

See the result in the cache with this query

```
select text from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
where text like '%Person%';
```

[image]

or

```
(@be int)SELECT  * FROM    Person.Person WHERE   BusinessEntityID = @be
```

**With a procedure the caching will be different**

Create the procedure

```
use test 
go
create procedure dbo.myproc @dbname varchar(255)
as
select * from sys.databases where name = @dbname
```

Run the proc

```
exec dbo.myproc @dbname= 'master';
```

Result in cache

```
select text from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
where text like '%myproc%';
```

[image]

or

```
create procedure dbo.myproc @dbname varchar(255)  as  select * from sys.databases where name = @dbname
```

**This can also happen when forced parameterization is enabled**

Enable forced parameterization

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED
```

Same query, without parameters

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Person.Person
WHERE   BusinessEntityID = 5
```

Result in cache

```
select text from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
where text like '%Person%'
```

[image]
or

```
(@0 int)select * from Person . Person where BusinessEntityID = @0
```